React App in Docker with Nginx Serving Without CSS
I am trying to deploy a React application using Docker and serve it with Nginx, mostly based on this. The app works perfectly when running locally using npm start, but when served through Docker and Nginx, the CSS is not applied, and the site appears as plain HTML.
Here is what I've done so far:
Dockerfile
FROM node:20-alpine AS build

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine

COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ssl /etc/nginx/ssl
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

EXPOSE 8080 8443

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]


Nginx.conf
events {
    worker_connections  4096;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name subdomain.domain.com;

        location / {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 8443 ssl;
        server_name subdomain.domain.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/cprivkey.pem;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;

        location /base-url/ {
            alias /usr/share/nginx/html/;
            try_files $uri /index.html;
        }

        location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index index.html;
            try_files $uri /index.html;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {
            expires off;
            # Just for testing
            # add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0";
            # add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
            log_not_found off;
        }
    }
}



Verified that files are correctly copied to /usr/share/nginx/html.
The CSS file is served and contains the expected styles.
Verified that index.html references the correct CSS file. (/usr/share/nginx/html/static/css/main..css)
The CSS file is requested and received without any 404 errors.
Console: No errors or warnings that indicate why the CSS isn't applied.
No errors found in the Nginx error logs.

What could be causing the CSS not to be applied when the app is served through Docker and Nginx, and how can I resolve this issue?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!
